# ThinkPad W500 ubuntu 12.10 64 poor battery performace

Tags: battery, thinkpad

This week I installed Ubuntu 12.10 64 on my ThinkPad W500. Great machine, powerful. But my battery lasts only around 2 hours.

What I've done:

- In the BIOS, I disabled the discrete graphic card (Intel 4500MHD).
- Switched off Bluetooth.

Are there other drivers or settings to use?

Comment: Why would you disable the discrete graphic card? It is installed so your computer uses less energy when only using 2D applications. A dedicated graphic card uses much more battery.

Comment: If you write `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -i "cpu mhz"` in the terminal, the does the CPU frequencies look right in idle situation(s)? If not, does your BIOS has any settings related to CPU frequency scaling?

Comment: You could try the solution outlined here; http://askubuntu.com/a/207270/82517

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly zero stats to back this up, and it's probably just wishful thinking, but `jupiter` (hardware and power management tool) seems to have improved my battery life (Thinkpad Edge). See pileofrocks's comment below.

If you want to try it out

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, terminal will pop up; type

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
```

enter password (you won't see it as you type, that's normal), confirm adding the repo, then:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

If you want to play around with settings yourself search for `jupiter` in the dash.

Comment: Thanks, i tried jupiter. It gave me information about cpu temperature. and about the battery time left. No matter what i selected it gave me only at least 2 hours (what i had before). Maybe i should try fedora 18?

Comment: @phipsalabim As far as I've understood, jupiter won't make much difference if the CPU frequency scaling is already working properly. It mainly limits the _maximum_ CPU usage, so in minimum use it makes even less difference. I did use it for a while too (Thinkpad Edge, too, btw) until I read more about it. See e.g.: http://askubuntu.com/questions/98972/

Comment: @pileofrocks thanks for this. It looks like there's too much wishful thinking on my part. Edited post.