# DELL Inspiron N4110 heating problem

Tags: 12.10

In My DELL Inspiron 4110 the cooling fan keeps on all the time and the left side of the laptop is really warm (It gets up to 100 celsius). It is not happening on Windows.

I tried to install bumblebeed but had no success. When I try to run `sudo bumblebeed`, I get:

```
[ERROR]No discrete video card found, quitting
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Few questions, which install instruction did you follow? Second , what are the GPUs (include result of `lspci | grep VGA`), also include result of `grep bumblebeed /var/log/syslog`

Comment: Also try and see if there is no processes eating up your resources. Start terminal, enter `top` and then press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to sort by processor usage, or install htop which is a bit easier to use.

Answer (score 3):

I found out that your laptop does not have a dedicated graphics processor like nvidia or ati, so bumblebee wont help you. ([more details here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1657660))

Now you may try jupiter, a power management app for linux distros

type these in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

More details on jupiter [HERE](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/jupiter-light-weight-power-and-hardware-control-applet.html) also [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98972/does-jupiter-really-improves-battery-power)

Hope that helps

Comment: and also you can install laptop-mode-tools.

Comment: Thank you, but didn´t work. :-(

Comment: @RicardoAcras are you using opengl based desktop application like cairo? or have you enabled compiz fusion desktop effects?

Comment: Didn´t do any of those. At least not consciously. Using only skype and chrome makes it heat that way.

Comment: I suggest you you try xubuntu or other lightweight version og ubuntu

Comment: @RicardoAcras Did you try installing xubuntu? Were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think this post might help you.

> [How do I get AMD/Intel Hybrid Graphics drivers to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/ubuntu-12-10-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-not-working)

Even my laptop had a same issue, I have installed graphics driver which can switch between High performance to power saving mode. now its working smooth.

Answer (score 0):

The graphics issue aside, your main problem is the overheating.

As it works on Windows but not on Ubuntu it means that your Laptop is using the CPU so its doing something. Obvious statement but the number of "rogue" processes that people have on their computers can cause this issue. The fact that the fan is constantly running and you still get heating issues means there is a rogue process.

Look at simple utilities like `top` to see what is using your CPU cycles.

Use the `services` command to determine that you haven't installed services like MYSQL or Apache that you don't need.

Is the brightness set to high? (indirect heat contributor)

Are there USB drives attached that are not self powered?

Or is the fan running at a lower rate than in Windows so the fan is not doing the job it needs to to cool down the CPU. (There are fan utilities that allow you to see how quickly the fan is spinning in both O/S systems)

Windows tends to have better fan control which is why I suggested the last item.

Run with the most basic video driver. If you installed one the has the 3D bells and whistles remove it to see if that helps.

Thats all I can think of at the moment, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Dell inspiron 3521 - Ubuntu 13.04 . Less sound of fan

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/linux-kernel-power-issue-fix.html

(Using tlp as well - http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/improve-power-usage-battery-life-in.html)