# Can my settings be customized automatically when I boot on battery power?

Tags: scripts, power-management, battery

Is it possible to tweak settings *if and only if* the computer starts on battery power?

#### Why?

I usually work without battery, but when I use a battery I want it to last as long as possible. For that purpose I use little tweaks (granola for minimal power consumption, switching off wifi and bluetooth, and brightness settings).

#### What?

Whenever I boot my laptop on battery I have to manually tweak all these settings. In the beginning that was OK, but now I want these tweaks to be done automatically. What I want to be tweaked automatically when *booting* on battery power is

1. setting the laptop in flight mode (no wifi nor bluetooth)
2. dimming the screen to 50%
3. disabling all usb inputs (I often leave a few things in usb slots, but I do not want them activated)
4. set the power mode in granola to minimal consumption (this needs `sudo`).

Any ideas? A script that runs automatically when logging in on battery? Anything?

Comment: The power settings can dim screen. Besides that: install jupiter (it works wonders on my system). http://askubuntu.com/questions/98972/does-jupiter-really-improves-battery-power

Comment: Hi Rinz, my screen does not dim automatically on battery power (12.10, Lenovo Ideapad Z580).

Comment: Regarding the dimming of the screen, this post explains a lot:
[http://www.vivaubuntu.cu.cc/dim-screen-backlight-on-when-on-battery/](http://www.vivaubuntu.cu.cc/dim-screen-backlight-on-when-on-battery/)

Answer (score 1):

You can insert your custom battery-saver commands to an executable file like this under folder "**/etc/pm/power.d**":

```
#!/bin/bash
if on_ac_power; then
    : # Do nothing
else
    rfkill block bluetooth # Turn OFF bluetooth
fi
exit 0
```

You can see a list of other options using **[PowerTOP](https://lesswatts.org/projects/powertop/)** utility.